# What is the O/F ratio of ethanolamine/H2O2?

Tags: fuel, hydrogen-peroxide

I've just read this question [What is the products of a catalyzed reaction between Hydrogen Peroxide and Ethanolamine with Copper(II) Chloride?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/50897/what-is-the-products-of-a-catalyzed-reaction-between-hydrogen-peroxide-and-ethan) and although its a very good question and an excellent answer I was still interested in what the oxidiser/fuel ratio might be. Is this fuel mixture similar enough to any other fuel to simply assume the O/F ratio?